# Changing background and text color of a ItemDelegate

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have the material design enabled (dark theme).

Some tutorials told me to use the background property to set my own Rectangle item with custom color. Like in this screenshot:

[image: Should later look like this]

But using this technique I dont have these nice ripple effects anymore. All I wanted to do was changing the background and text color of all items.

So I tried changing propertys of background without luck. At startup the debug output told me there is no color property in background.

So I came up with a "hacky" way using Bindings... Now the properties exist!?

Is this the best way to accomplish my goal? The ripple effects appear on clicking but I dont have a good feeling with this. I dont understand why the property exist when using Bindings and why they dont exist when using normal databinding.

```
ItemDelegate {
    width: ListView.view.width
    height: contentItem.implicitHeight + 10

    topPadding: 5
    bottomPadding: 5

    highlighted: ListView.view.currentIndex === model.index

    //background.color: highlighted ? "#81A3CF" : "#B3B2B2"
    Binding {
        target: background
        property: "color"
        value: highlighted ? "#81A3CF" : "#B3B2B2"
    }

    text: model.index + (highlighted ? " [highlighted]" : "")

    //contentItem.color: "black"
    Binding {
        target: contentItem
        property: "color"
        value: "black"
    }

    onClicked: {
        if(ListView.view.currentIndex === model.index)
            ListView.view.currentIndex = -1;
        else
            ListView.view.currentIndex = model.index
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simple:

`background` is declared as a `Item` - and `Item` has no `color`, so you can't change it, before it is assigned a concrete `Item` that has a `color`. So when you execute the `QML`-file, the `Rectangle` is not yet available, until everything is created. This is when the `Binding` will set the color.

If you don't need it to be bound to anything, another solution is to use:

```
Component.onCompleted: background.color = 'green'
```

Otherwise, I deem the `Binding`-trick to be fine (*but this is opinion!*)

Comment: Ah ok, so I will stay with Binding for my background because it depends on highlighted. I am very sad that I have implement such basic things on my own like what highlighted means and the onClicked event. I definately think such things should stay in the library.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can control an `ItemDelegate` background and text color:

- Set text and background color indirectly by setting `highlighted` boolean property
- Set text color by setting `palette` colors (light, highlightedText, text, window)
- Set background color by supplying a background delegate

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ListView {
        model: 10
        width: 300
        height: parent.height
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            background: Rectangle { 
                color: highlighted ? palette.light : palette.window
            }
            width: parent.width
            highlighted: ListView.isCurrentItem
            text: index + " " + (highlighted ? "[highlighted]" : "")
            palette.light: "blue"
            palette.highlightedText: "#ffe"
            palette.text: "black"
            palette.window: "lightgrey"
            onClicked: ListView.view.currentIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACkHicdVJNS8QwEL33VwzxoiyUFW8B8VAvggdXxIt46MdsGjZNlnTqrkj/u5O01AbWCRTe5OW9mUd1d3SeYEe7QdeHTCcwL5wl70yfvZQK4ScDrmfd07vG0wxDda5BI+F2u3ROuqFWwt32r9WiVi1JOJYeLeUTXG5ZAFVJKOGJsHuc0cojVFXWB+XdYBsJr1hTaZVhDiSkULUzzkto2cIEG2zggY0NEmEeOyAXXA1EziYaY4LmZebBI0ruVzZyiSfXfTH48CIslPAJz5yDtg2eYQOCzwau01nFxwp/Cp5WiJtEJNmGryszoLjIWCm9RWdxtd//w51GYzFO+jJjSos5UVJ5/E55zhaGf50kiq/wqec04tr30/rLyynwMRt/AZCGu4M=)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're changing the background color of your item delegate. The normal way to visually highlight the selected item in a ListView is to create a component (usually using a rectangle) and assign it to the ListView's highlight property, then set the ListView's highlightFollowsCurrentItem to true. The ListView will hide and show the highlight component as appropriate when the currentIndex changes, and you can specify various transition effects if you desire.

Comment: What if my item also has a background color? Wouldn't the highlight rectangle be hidden underneath the items?

Comment: Yes, I believe it would. Do all of your items have the same background color or do they differ? I've always used a rectangle the size of the ListView, as a child of the ListView, to provide the list's background, in which case the highlight rectangle appears above the background. But if you need different-colored rows, that won't work.